# Push data to array without index

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, multidimensional-array

I'd like to know how can i add this

```
{ post_id: 1, text: "text", creation: "date" }
```

to the "posts" in a array like this

```
 var posts = [

    {
        post_id: 5, 
        text: "text", 
        creation: "date"
    },
    {
        group: "favPosts",
        posts: [
                    { post_id: 2, text: "text", creation: "date" }, 
                    { post_id: 7, text: "text", creation: "date" }
               ]
    },
    {
        post_id: 8, 
        text: "text", 
        creation: "date"
    }
]
```

I've already tried searching a hundred times but i can't seem to find a answer that suits my case, I've been trying to insert it with commands like slice and push but i can't seem to get it right, i'm still a beginner in javascript.

PS: I've come a solution but i don't think it's very "efficient";

```
addToGroup("favPosts");

function addToGroup(group) {

    for(id in posts) {

        if(posts[id].group == group){

            posts[id].posts.push({ post_id: 10, text: "did it", creation: "date" });

            console.log(posts[id]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That isn't valid. You would need to make `people` be an array.

`people: [{name: "name", surname: "surname" }, { ... }, ...]`

Comment: You question would perhaps be clearer if you didn't have `name:"name"` and `surname:"surname"` everywhere. It's really not clear *where* you are trying to insert your value since you seen to have identical objects all over the place.

Comment: If you knew or determined the index of the `group` within the outer `collection`, it would be: `collection[indexOfGroup].people.push(person);` "[Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)"

Comment: @forgivenson Sorry it's fixed now, Matt Burland i think i made the array "better" now sorry, Jonathan Lanowski Thanks i'll look into that but i'll see if i can get a solution to my problem as it is now.

Answer (score 1):

This should work with a push, I don't see why this wouldn't work.
Here is an example, I just used angular to easily display in HTML, not needed for what you are doing:http://plnkr.co/edit/PBCYxfjMqV3jzggMHJZ7?p=preview

```
var people = [
    {
        name: "Joe",
        surname: "surname"
    },
    { 
        group: "name",
        people: [{ name: "name", surname: "surname" }, { name: "name", surname: "surname"     }]
    },
    {
        name: "James",
        surname: "surname"
    }
];

var person = { name: "Jennifer", surname: "surname" };

people.push(person);
```

Comment: Thanks but the data is meant to be pushed to "group: "name", >people<" not the "main" array which you named as people too